# Rerendering angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular component that displays some information(for the purpose of this scenario).In my typesript component i have a function that gets new data to be displayed.
For the sake of the scenario let's say that the component can not render the new information unless i rerender it.At this time i am doing this using setTimeout() like this:

```
updateData(){
  this.data=this.dataService.getData();
  this.showComponent=false;
  setTimeout(()=>{this.showComponent=true;},1);
```

}

This way i am sure that my component will be rerendered.
I know this is a pretty dumb way of resolving the issue.
How can i do this better?

Comment: *component can not render the new information unless i rerender it.* why?

Comment: For the sake of the scenarion, let's ask why the component can not render the new information unless you rerender it?

Comment: [the famous XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) *"The issue arises when the person with the problem thinks that they themselves have a partial solution to their problem, and only ask for the parts they think they are "stuck" on. On the other side, the people offering to help lack information as to the root problem, and thus cannot provide ultimately useful information"* in some cases, the partial solution may be wrong. I suspect this is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataService.getData()` should return an Observable, to which you subscribe. Then you set the `showComponent` to true.

Something like this:

```
this.dataService.getData(
    (data) => {
        this.data = data;
        this.showComponent = true;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ChangeDetectorRef doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Angular Change detection is triggered on async operations like DOM events, http requests and so on. So if you update values synchronously Change Detection engine can miss those changes.

So there are two ways of solving this issue: run `setTimeout` like you did or `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` to mark component for update on the next digest loop or`ChangeDetectorRef.detectCahnges()` to run check immediately.